# WAMP Directory re routing as if by magic

Tags: .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

So I am horrendously stuck on this. On my WAMP server I have a directory in www called b4pv2. It looks like this

```
wamp64
    www
        b4pv2
            config
                startup.php
            htdocs
                index.php
            widgets
                /*various *.php files with HTML content mainly */
```

However when I visit localhost/b4pv2 it redirects automatically to htdocs/index.php. I have no .htaccess files and no rewrite rules...etc. anywhere as a consequence and can't figure out why this is happening.

If I create an index.php file and put it in that directory it in the b4pv2 directory it still redirects and if I create a sub directory in htdocs with an index.php file it still reverts back to htdocs.

Bizarely I can access my css files...etc. without any issues though in the browser.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Or is this all code written by you?

Comment: You should really be creating a Virtual Host for each of your projects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Written by me just a small project. I've got laravel projects running inside WAMP but not at the same time of course. Only a few files never had this before. Just tried deleting and cloning from git again and it still had the same problem. Changed directory name for the root directory and now it works strangely but if I change it back it doesn't. Does WAMP perhaps have some bizarre htaccess caching from a previous project??? Sounds absurd but I can't think what else it could possibly be.

Comment: No, No caching like that, but your browser might be doing some caching